# Jasper Unicode issue with Field Reference but not Resource Bundle Reference

Tags: java, unicode, jasper-reports, pdf-generation

I am using Jasper Reports to produce PDF reports.  When I have diacriticals in resources ($R expressions), they display fine, but when (in the same report, even in the same TextField element, just swapping the innermost expression) I have Field Reference ($F expression), the diacritical mark is not displayed. "Mĕdical" comes out as "Mdical".

It can't be font or style (because with the identical font and style, $R expressions display the diacritical without problems).  It can't be encoding (UTF-8, although I've also tried others) for the same reason.

I've stepped into the code in the debugger and I know without question that the string being returned to Jasper Reports contains the diacritical character.  What could be causing this problem and where can I look to find it?

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a two-part problem.

1. I was using a different diacritical character in the $F expression
   from the $R expression, and the $F diacritical was not supported by
   my font.
2. I was HTML-escaping the string that fed to Jasper Reports, and I
   needed to XML-escape it instead.